# Is the book "Practical English Usage" sufficient for achieving native-like English?

Tags: grammar

Is the book "Practical English Usage" sufficient for achieving native-like English? I want to know as much as a native speaker does

Comment: You can't learn everything from a single book. Language learning doesn't work that way. How is that reference book going to help you with idioms, pronunciation, phrasal verbs, slang, intonation, stress.. etc.?

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly a good reference source to use **together** with other texts.  However, to become truly proficient my suggestion is to read as much as you can (online, novels ,magazines, signs etc.). Also listen to English on TV, the radio and online.  If you hear or read English words and expressions that you are not sure of then use this book  to learn more.  The whole English language cannot be encapsulated in any one book.  Use texts as an adjunct to your learning in the real world of English.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others, but I would also like to add that listening to music and lyrics and watching English movies you enjoy is also a good way to learn. Use a book as a reference.